# ¿ How to create a table ( in .rdlc report ) by code?

Tags: vb.net, report

I'm doing a program in vb.net ... I was ordered to create a new report where I have to select a start date and end date, and during that period take that data and print them all in a table. Calculations and others, is the least important... 
What I face now is that this report would have to be dynamic ... and I dont know how to create a table ( tablix ) for a report ( .rdlc ) by code.

¿How could I achieve that?

Comment: The tablix isn't dynamic, just the data to populate it.

Comment: Thank u for the response